# Using Eigen rankupdate

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen

We solve (via Cholesky decomp) large electrical networks in which only a small percentage of values change between iterations. The network is very sparse and SPD. Solve requires that need to factorize the entire matrix at each step.

My understanding (if correct) is that there are methods available, such as rankUpdate, to directly adjust the factorized matrix which may improve solve times. In our case, each element change results in a change to 2 or 3 rows, and the corresponding 2 or 3 columns.

Can anyone offer a brief discussion and simple example of how rankUpdate is used, or correct my understanding?

This would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

In Eigen's Cholesky solvers, rank-updates are available only for dense solvers, e.g.:

```
LDLT chol(A); // initial factorization
chol.rankUpdate(V,s);
```

At this stage `chol` is equvalent to the factorization of `A+s*V*V^T`.

For sparse problems, this is not supported yet but CHOLMOD from Suite-Sparse does support rank-updates. The best, and likely simplest, way would be add such a `rankUpdate` method to the `Eigen::CholmodLLT` class as a thin wrapper to the underlying CHOLMOD routine.

Comment: Yes, a closer read of chol.rankUpdate() shows it is for dense, so thanks for that.  Unfortunately we work in Windows and getting CHOLMOD running is a major undertaking.